# docker compose application unable to see redis server

Tags: python, docker, celery, docker-compose

I'm trying to put up 3 apps using docker. One of them is a flask web app, the other is a redis server, and the other one is a celery app that will communicate with the flask one via redis.
Now the first 2 seem to come up without any issues, but for the flask app i'm getting this error:

> celery_1 exited with code 1

My docker-compose.yml file looks like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "7998:7998"
    command: "gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:7998 --log-level TRACE common_apps:app"
  celery:
    build: .
    command: "celery -A common_apps.celery_app worker"
```

And if I cut out the celery part and launch it individually, the error message I get is not being able to find the redis host (but this may be because the hostname redis is only present within the docker-compose context)

Any thoughts on what's broken here ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the .env file was being ignored. After I moved the values from the .env file to the docker-compose.yml file, the application started working as intended